# configuration script init.lua for neovim instead of init.vim

Tags: neovim

As Lua is now built-in as of neovim 0.2 (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ), can one use a ~/.config/nvim/init.lua configuration file instead of init.vim?

What would an example of init.lua look like?

Because vimscript is driving me crazy.

Comment: You might be interested in the conversation in this Reddit thread regarding why configuration in Lua would be considered valuable: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/6bfn33/any_documentation_on_how_to_use_native_lua/

Comment: These days you can the [vimpeccable plugin](https://github.com/svermeulen/vimpeccable) to migrate your vimrc to lua fairly easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for `init.lua` is available now in nightly builds and will be released in Neovim 0.5:

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7895

Comment: The feature seems to planned fo 0.3 now.

Comment: Now milestone is set to 0.5

Answer (score -1):

**No.**

I'm going to go ahead and answer this since the message from core developers seems to have been that VimL will not be replaced for this purpose. See [Thiago's comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/31vxk1/configuring_neovim_without_vimscript/) a few years back on Reddit. To summarise, back then the idea was that Lua would act as a runtime for VimL although that PR eventually [stalled](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/243#issuecomment-153318119) due to performance concerns.

So for the time being at least, you can write plugins in Lua but you can't use Lua as the configuration language.